# SQL Server rename table takes very long

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to rename a table on sql server using the following command:
`alter table <schema>.<old_name> RENAME TO <new_name>;`

The table is fairly small: approximately 500 rows with 15 columns. The command runs for more than 15 minutes before I kill it. 
I have verified that I have permissions to rename the tables since I have renamed a couple of other tables in the same schema (which took less than a minute because they were empty).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use sp_who or sp_who2 to see what it is waiting on, there is probably a lock on the table.

Comment: are you using Oracle or sql-Server?, "RENAME" is not a valid word in sql-server

Answer (score -1):

Copy the data into another table (select * into), then just drop and recreate the table using the correct name, then insert the data back in.